# Extracting statistics from raster within extent of a polygon using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, statistics

I have a polygon representing the extent of a study area. This polygon is overlaid to a raster representing the quality of land, which is classified into 5 classes (from bad [1] to good [5]). I would like to have ArcMap (10.1, advanced license) calculate how much land within the polygon is bad, how much is mediocre, and so on.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe I find the answer myself. I can clip the raster to the extent of the polygon, and then open the raster attribute table and calculate how many pixels fall in each quality class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [Zonal Histogram](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/zonal-histogram.htm). As Input raster of feature zone data, specify your polygon(s). As Input value raster, the land quality raster. The output table will show each land quality class as a row, each polygon class as a column. Thus if you have more than one polygon, you may want to group them into classes beforehand, using a unique value for each class in a special column. This column is specified as the Zone field in the tool. An alternative is to select only the polygon you are interested in and only then run the tool.

Comment: Thank you for your useful reply. My solution led essentially to the same thing, but it was a little more tricky.

Comment: Thought as much, manually I would Clip, turn the raster to points, Join with polygon and Summarize.